# Flex: iFrame Obscures Content When Scrolling Vertically

Tags: apache-flex, iframe

I'm using an iFrame in my Flex 3 project. It looks fine. But, if the browser window is small and scrollbars are visible, then I've got a problem. When the user scrolls down the iFrame stays in place at the top of the browser and covers content. Unfortuantely, in this case, I have to use an iFrame. How should I prevent the iFrame from obscuring parts of my site when the user scrolls?

```
<flexiframe:IFrame id="myIFrame"  source="http://www.mysite.com/myStuff.html"  x="315" y="20" width="498" height="65" scrollPolicy="off" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think You hadn't aligned the Iframe properly

Use the HBox and VBox as possible everywhere.

avoid using x y positions.